# To make height of rows from 2 to 50=118 using vba

Tags: excel, vba

What changes do i need to make in this code To make height of rows from 2 to 50=118

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 50
Rows("i:i").RowHeight = 118
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, can do it in one fell swoop.

```
Rows("2:50").RowHeight = 118
```

In your code `i` was inside the quotes so the code was looking for row "i" which doesn't exist.

You could write

```
Rows(i & ":" & i).RowHeight = 118
```

but there doesn't seem much point.